# Perturbations of Lattices

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

This is a little idea I've been playing with. I was wondering if anyone has seen anything similar or if they have any questions/insights:

Let $\lambda:=\{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i w_i|\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $w_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for $i=1,...,n$ is a set of independent vectors. That is, $\lambda$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We define an $\epsilon$-perturbation of $\lambda$ to be $\rho_V(\lambda)=\lambda+V(\lambda)$ where $V$ is a vector field $V:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for each $l\in\lambda$, $\|V(l)\|\le\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a fixed real constant greater than zero. I pose the following question:

What are some good ways of measuring how much of the group structure on $\lambda$ is preserved under the image of $\rho_V$?

One notion I thought about a bit is "mixing". If we map the image of each lattice point into the unit disk (after normalizing), we can measure how "mixed" the perturbation is. Intuitively, if $\epsilon$ is small and sufficiently mixed then the group structure might be somewhat preserved.

Just something to play with that I have been thinking about.

Comment: After $\lambda$ is perturbed.

Comment: I realized a mistake in my write-up. I'll edit it.